# Does $f(x,y)=(x^2y+x,6x+y^2)$ have a local inverse at $(1,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be given by 
$$
f(x,y)=(x^2y+x,6x+y^2).
$$
A direct calculation shows that $\det Df(1,1)=0$. The key assumption in the Inverse Function Theorem is not satisfied.

Here is my **question**:

> Does there exist a local inverse of $f$ at $(1,1)$?

Comment: $f(-0.90787,3.2581) = f(1,1)$

Comment: So I have what might be an answer but it could be fundamentally flawed. I'm not sure. But if you try letting $y = 1-\varepsilon$, use the second component to solve for $x$, then plug the value of $x$ back into the first component, what you find is that $\varepsilon$ solves a cubic equation. There must be a smallest nonzero solution, which would suggest to me that if you pick anything between $1$ and $1-\varepsilon$ (for that smallest $\varepsilon$), you'd have a range of $y$s that do not give a solution. Then you can pick your $x$ in an interval as well. Thus $f$ would be $1$-$1$ in a small

Comment: ... nbhd around $(1,1)$ so it would be locally invertible?

Comment: As long as $f$ is injective in some neighborhood $U$ of $(1,1)$, it has an inverse on $f(U)$. The problem is with differentiability of its inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(x,y)=(x^2y+x,6x+y^2)$, we have
$$
\frac{\partial\,f}{\partial(x,y)}
=\begin{bmatrix}2xy+1&6\\x^2&2y\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}2xy+1&6\\x^2&2y\end{bmatrix}=4xy^2+2y-6x^2
$$
we get
$$
\det\frac{\partial\,f(1,1)}{\partial(x,y)}=0
$$
Thus, the Jacobian is singular at $(1,1)$.

Since
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&-3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3&6\\1&2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
the singular direction is $\begin{bmatrix}1&-3\end{bmatrix}$. Looking at
$$
f(1+t,1-3t)=\left(2-5t^2-3t^3,7+9t^2\right)
$$
we want to subtract $(2,7)$ and rotate with $\begin{bmatrix}-5&9\\9&5\end{bmatrix}$ to align the cusp with the $x$-axis.
$$
(f(1+t,1-3t)-(2,7))\begin{bmatrix}-5&9\\9&5\end{bmatrix}=\left(t^2(106+15t),-27t^3\right)
$$
Adjusting the direction a very small amount, we see that
$$
(f(1+t,1-(3-a)t)-(2,7))\begin{bmatrix}-5&9\\9&5\end{bmatrix}\approx(106t^2,-27t^3+19at)
$$
which loops and intersects itself at $t\approx\pm\sqrt{\frac{19a}{27}}$.

Here is the curve for $a=0.1$:

[image]

The point of self-intersection is near the approximated point $(7.45926,0)$

Thus, no matter how close we get to $(1,1)$, there is the image of a line that gets mapped to a loop which intersects itself. Therefore, the function is not invertible near $(1,1)$.

Comment: "Thus, the inverse, is singular." No, the Jacobian determinant being zero is not enough to ensure noninvertibility (and, actually, this might be the most important message to give to the OP...).

Comment: @Did: that was a typo, but the Jacobian being singular does not immediately imply the function is not injective. The one dimensional analog being $x^3$ which is injective although its derivative at $0$ is $0$. The discussion after that is to show that as close as we can get to $(1,1)$, there are points for which $x\ne y$ yet $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: @robjohn: I have never seen the discussion about "singular direction". Do you have any references for this trick?